# Splitting a String into several Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, split, substring

How would I go about splitting a String in several places where ever a certain character occurs.

For example, here is the String

"10067829311288"

When looping through the String, if the digit is a "1", it will take the next the next two characters and split, if not, it will take only one. Here's how it should be split.

100 67 82 93 112 88

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How come the double 1 results in `112` instead of `1128`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "10067829311288";
    final List<Integer> split = new LinkedList<>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length()) {
        final char c = s.charAt(i);
        final int remain = s.length() - i;
        final int step;
        if (c == '1') {
            step = Math.min(remain, 3);
        } else {
            step = Math.min(remain, 2);
        }
        split.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + step)));
        i += step;
    }
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Or, with regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "10067829311288";
    final List<Integer> split = new LinkedList<>();
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("1?\\d{2}");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        split.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
    }
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples, I couldn't get my head around how to do the "step" part. Can you also explain what this regex does "1?\\d{2}" please?

Comment: the regex `1?\\d{2}` matches an optional `1` greedily followed by two digits. So if there isn't a 1 it will grab two digits, if there is a one it will grab that and two more digits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution.

```
public void split() {
    System.out.println(split("10067829311288"));
}

public List<String> split(String text) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("1?\\d\\d").matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Update: simplified my regex after seeing how Boris the Spider did his regex.

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing \\d{2} is the same as \\d\\d?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
"10067829311288".split("(?<=\\G(1\\d\\d|[02-9]\\d))");
```

demo

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("10067829311288".split("(?<=\\G(1\\d\\d|[02-9]\\d))")));
```

output: `[100, 67, 82, 93, 112, 88]`

---

`\\G` represents position of last match (split) and if first match doesn't exists it represents start of the String.

`(?<=regex)` is [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism

`\\d` represents digit

`|` is OR